# Calculate two coupled equation with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

This time, it's not really an important question, but maybe an interesting one.

Let us assume we have two variables `x` ans `y`. This variables depend on time (a discrete time). We have a starting condition and want to iterate them over time.  Let us assume we have `x[0] = a` and `y[0] = b`. We now want to calculate all the given points for a small amount of time and we know the following relation between these two variables:

```
x[n+1] = x[n] + y[n]
y[n+1] = y[n] + np.sin(x[n+1])
```

Of course we can do it with a loop:

```
x[0], y[0] = a, b

for n in range(100): # just an arbitrary iteration
    x[n+1] = x[n] + y[n]
    y[n+1] = y[n] + np.sin(x[n+1])
```

Okay. This is possible, if I didn't make some mistakes =). What I want is maybe to have a much better and more `numpy`-like way to solve it without an iteration. 
I tried to come up with some shifting or other stuff. I just want a calculation on the arrays without a loop, cause loops are really boring. I just had an idea with recursive function calls, but I have to try it out tomorrow in the morning.

Comment: This kind of recurrence relation is the prototypical case of something that cannot be written in an efficient vectorised form in NumPy.  If speed matters, use a different language, like Cython.  Maybe `numexpr` can optimise this as well, not sure.

Comment: I was thinking that it isn't possible, but wanted to ask anyways.

Comment: using xrange will help if you are going for more than a 100, but ya I think this is exactly the kind of operation you can't do in numpy.

You have a ton of typo's.  I edited one for you (when you are assigning the 0 variables), but you also used n in stead of i.

Comment: You have written discrete equations. If that is genuinely what you need to solve, then there isn't much else you can do. However, if what you really need is to solve a continuous ODE, then scipy has several routines specifically for this purpose http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#integrators-of-ode-systems

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters said above, this can't be nicely vectorized. If you want a quick fix that should help with the speed, consider the `inline` option from `scipy.weave`. The code below is a script that gives a working example of this for your desired discrete system. This should be much better than a Python for-loop for large arrays.

```
import scipy.weave as weave
import numpy as np

def simulate_x_and_y(x,y,a,b):

    x[0] = a; y[0] = b;
    n_range = len(x)

    code = """
    #include <math.h>

    for(int n = 1; n < n_range; n++){
        x(n) = x(n-1) + y(n-1);
        y(n) = y(n-1) + sin(x(n)); 
    }
    """

    weave.inline(code, ['x','y','n_range'], 
                 type_converters = weave.converters.blitz,
                 compiler = "gcc", headers=["<math.h>"]
                )


if __name__ == "__main__":

    x = np.zeros(10);
    y = np.zeros(10);
    a = 4.0; b = 10.0;

    print "Before:"
    print x
    print y

    simulate_x_and_y(x,y,a,b)

    print "After:"
    print x
    print y
```

Comment: `weave` is deprecated and slated for removal; the documentation says things like "most testing has been done on Windows 2000" and "Requirements: Python: I use 2.1.1". The GitHub page for the standalone version recommends that new code use Cython.

Comment: I think a simple use of `ctypes` makes more sense for a small example like this, rather than incurring the dependency on Cython and having it in the build process for such a small use case. But thanks for pointing out the deprecation of weave (judging from the date of the GitHub readme, it looks like this happened in 2014, so two years after this answer was posted).